# Is the following statement true? $P: \forall x > 0, \exists y > 0 \text{ such that } y < x$

Tags: real-analysis

I have attempted the problem but I am still confused if it is right.

Would really appreciate some advice.

My proof

Let $x>0$ be arbitrary.

So, $y=\frac{x}{2}$.

If $x=1$ then $y=\frac{1}{2}$.

Hence, $y<x$.

So, the statement is true .

Comment: Honestly, I can't really tell what you are trying to say with your proof or why you put the example of $y=1$. Just take $y=\frac{x}{2}$ (which I think you thought about) and conclude the statement is true

Comment: You have not specified what universal set we are working with.  It is not true in the case of the universal set being the integers for instance... there does not exist a positive integer less than $1$.

Comment: As for the statement about real numbers, yes... for every positive real number there is indeed some corresponding positive real number which is smaller... or rephrased, yes $0<\frac{x}{2}<x$ is true for all positive real numbers $x$.  This follows from definitions of `<`.

Comment: It's a good start, but you need to show that the $y > 0$ and that $y < x$ from your definitions of division and $<$ or some lemmas/theorems that can be derived from them.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea of how to prove it. Some critiques:

1. You need show that "$\exists y>0$ such that" .... (some other stuff). So you found a candidate $y = \frac{x}{2}$. How do you know $y > 0$? Make it as clear as possible to the reader. Also if you want to get nitpicky, is this candidate $y = \frac{x}{2}$ in your universal set of numbers? For example, if your universal set were integers, maybe $y$ is not always an integer. But I believe your intended universal set is the real numbers so half a real number is always a real number.
2. ... "such that $y > x$". How do you know your candidate $y = \frac{x}{2}$ is in fact less than $x$? I see you gave an example but you need to show it works for any arbitrary $x >0$.

Most of this probably seems outrageously obvious but it's good to be very thorough in your writing when you're first learning how to write a proof. Once you're a bit more comfortable with proofs and are onto harder material, you don't need such obvious details.